# MySQL 8 Warning: SQL_NO_CACHE is deprecated

Tags: caching, warnings, deprecated, deprecation-warning, mysql-8.0

When issuing a statement to MySQL8 server:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE *
FROM <table-name>;
```

I get this warning:

> Warning, 1681, 'SQL_NO_CACHE' is deprecated and will be removed in a
>   future release.

I would like to ask if there is any successor of the `SQL_NO_CACHE` that works or is planned to work with MySQL 8.x?

Does `SQL_NO_CACHE` actually work with MySQL 8.x or it is omitted by the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=10837 says:

Since 8.0 still has (i.e. silently ignores) the `SQL_NO_CACHE` syntax and always returns false on the `have_query_cache` variable, maintain deprecation warnings for both like we do in 5.7 for a while.

more readings on this subject:
https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-retiring-support-for-the-query-cache/

"*Although MySQL Query Cache was meant to improve performance, it has serious scalability issues and it can easily become a severe bottleneck.*"

and

"*The query cache has been disabled-by-default since MySQL 5.6 (2013)*"

Answer (score 2):

Just noticed it, damn it was so useful -_-
Keep using it until it's removed or try `SELECT column, now() FROM myTable` instead. 
I suppose the call will force mysql to not use the cache.